Mutually affecting object constraint issues
I'm currently having a problem with mutually affecting object constraints.
I'm modeling a furniture hinge, with a couple of moving parts and funny angles, and I want it to behave mechanically accurately, and I'm trying to achieve this with object constraints.
I have two main parts. They (should) work as a mechanical elbow, in which the rotation of the secondary object maps to a lower level of rotation of the active object.

To achieve this I made a setup in which the rotation of the secondary object is determined by the rotation of the active object, and the position of the active one is determined by the position at the tip of the secondary one, as you can (hopefully) see in the gif. So the dark orange object have a constraint that copies the rotation of the light orange one with the appropriate ratio, and I parented an empty object at its tip, that will follow his rotation. And the light orange object copies the position of the that empty, accompanying the dark orange one as everything moves. So I rotate the active object, and the whole mechanism should follow.

But I'm having a couple of problems with this setup.
First, when I rotate the light orange object and undo that rotation, both objects rotations are undone, but his position is not. It gets stuck at the position before the undo, and as soon as I try to grab, rotate or do any alterations to it, then it automatically snaps back to the position it should be (this can be seen in the gif as well). And second: every time I open this file, that same object always starts at the world origin, and as son as I try to do anything to it, then it again snaps back to the proper position.
My guess is that, since both object constraints are mutually affecting each other, this might be throwing off the way blender evaluates the constraints and causing the mismatches.
Is there a way fix this issue? or even to reproduce the effect I'm looking for in a more straightforward way? Thanks!

You're right! this snap problem is  caused by a dependency cycle. The right way would be if the tip object drives the movement of the arm with a 'look at' constraint (could be Damped Track or Stretch to, some of these) and the shovel is point constrained to the this tip object. A good tip is to make a proper rig, there is a chance of screwing things up without the rig, that's it's duty.

Oh ok, that's what I figured.
I'm gonna play with some of your suggestions. Thanks!
